# Can you mix regular and injected parameters in a constructor in Angular Dart?

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

In Angular Dart, can you mix regular parameters and injected parameters in a class constructor?  When I instantiate the class, I get a missing arguments error.  For example:

If you have:

```dart
class Foo {
  String b;
  Http _http;

  Foo(String this.b, Http this._http);
}

Foo foo = new Foo('beta'); 

//Error missing arguments.
```

My work around

```dart
class Foo {
  String b;
  Http _http;

  Foo(Http this._http);
}

Foo foo = new Foo(); 
foo.b = 'beta';
```

What I would like:

```dart
class Foo {
  String b;
  Http _http;

  Foo(String this.b) {
    //inject an instance of _http here?
  }
}

Foo foo = new Foo('beta');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the injector as a second parameter and let your `Foo` class' constructor pull the HTTP from the injector
like show in the answer to this question [Manual injection in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899346)

Comment: I have a deeply nested class structure that I was trying to avoid passing the parent injector down the class hierarchy and instead find a way to get it globally. From this and the Manual Injection question, I gather that is the only way.